# Error while generating metadata

Tags: c#, .net, .net-remoting

```
class myremoteobject:MarshalByRefObject 
{
    public myremoteobject()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hi there");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpChannel chn = new HttpChannel(1234);
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chn, false);
        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(myremoteobject), "abc", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
        Console.WriteLine("server started.... press any key to stop");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I have these simple classes but while I am trying to generate metadata from it using **soapsuds** tool
like this:- `soapsuds -ia:server -nowp -oa:metadata.dll`

I am getting error

**Error: Invalid schema data., No Bindings with SOAP, RPC and Encoded elements**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have received this error in the past because soapsuds.exe expects a different encoding than that provided by ASP.NET.  In such a case, wsdl.exe worked for me.  It is a difference between remoting (soapsuds.exe) and web services (wsdl.exe).